# How to access complicated JSON array & object data?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am stuck in accessing complicated JSON data for the application in angular, and this is how it look.

```
{
"members": [
{
"member_id": "1",
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"education_and_career": "[{\"highest_education\":\"MSc\",\"occupation\":\"Lead Developer\",\"annual_income\":\"100,000 USD\"}]",
}]};
```

I can access member_id, first name using data.member_id but I am not able to access data.education_and_career.highest_education value. I know it may look very simple but I am stuck so I really appreciate your time.

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: `education_and_career` is not an array, it's a string, which contains JSON-encoded data. You need to `JSON.parse` that string to turn it into an array you can access elements of. Or you should rather fix whatever is producing that JSON to not make it double encode your data.

Comment: Hi, actually I can't change the backend data, could you please do me a favor by elaborating how can JSON.parse to only specific value?

Comment: `let arr = JSON.parse(data.education_and_career)`, then access `arr` as array…?!

Comment: Actually I am returning the data I am receiving from the backend and looping in front end using angular ngfor.

Comment: Actually that doesn't make any fundamenal difference to what I said.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I really appreciate your help. The issue is resolved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`"education_and_career"` is a field that contains a JSON string therefore you can't use it like a normal array. you can however use the `JSON.parse` method in order to parse it. so in order to access the hieghest_education field you would do it like so:

```
JSON.parse(data.education_and_career)[0].highest_education
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse education_and_career property to JSON. Below is sample with map function or for loop

```
var data = {
  "members": [{
    "member_id": "1",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "education_and_career": "[{\"highest_education\":\"MSc\",\"occupation\":\"Lead Developer\",\"annual_income\":\"100,000 USD\"}]",
  }]
};
var parsed=data.members.map(i=>JSON.parse(i.education_and_career));
console.log("parsed",parsed)

for (i = 0; i < data.members.length; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(data.members[i].education_and_career))
}
```

Comment: I will try this out.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `education_and_career` is not an object array. You need to use the String.replace() method to remove \ and convert it to JSON data and you would be able to access the highest_education value like education_and_career[0].highest_enducation_value or so.

Comment: If we're looking at the complete JSON response, then the backslashes are just fine and *must not* be replaced…

Comment: Sounds like you're right. Assuming that other key and value pairs look JSON object but that the education_and_career array looks kinda string.